# Move an artifact from 1 model to another in AX7

Tags: models, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax7, d3fo

I am wokring in AX7, I need to move some artifacts from Application Suite User Model to my new created model.

**Scenario:**

1. I created a model named "My Model"
2. created a project named "MyProject" and set its model to "My Model"
3. I have a table named "MyTable" in Application Suite User Model.

**Problem:**

I opened MyTable in Aplication Explorer and right click on it, it doesn't show me option "Add to project", and if I select "Customize" option, it says that

"MyTable cannot be customized in MyProject, Customization is only possible if the models are in the same package"

**So how can I move an artifact from Application Suite User Model to My Model ??**

Comment: Make sure your model is created in Application Suite package and in user layer to move the object. Otherwise I don't think there is a way to move. I also experienced corrupting Ax trying to move objects between different layers in Ax 7.

Comment: @Pradeep, i've found its solution and it is very easy. see my answer.

Comment: That's good. In my case I created a extensible control and tried to move same and got into trouble. One artifact without dependency with other objects might not have issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found its solution, it is very simple.

Brief:

Just move your desired artifact from back-end, cut the file from "application suite usr model" and paste it to "My Model", Here you GO !! Now when you will open Application explorer, you will see that you artifact has been moved to "My Model".

In detail:

Go to below path and cut the artifact you want to move to other model.

**C:\Packages\application suite\application suite usr model\AxTables**

Now go to below path and paste that artifact here.

**C:\Packages\My Model\AxTables**

Open Application Explorer and find the artifact you moved, you will see that it is moved to you desired model.

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to link this here first: https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/193502

Essentially you can either do the Windows Explorer move, much as Shahrukh has also mentioned, or you can Cut and Paste between two projects with a solution.

In a little more detail:
Your solution should contain at least two projects: one project working in the model you want to move the elements from and one project working in the model you want to move the elements to. Select the elements you want to move, Cut (or ctrl+x), select the project you want to move to and Paste (or ctrl+v). Depending on the number of elements you are moving, this could take a few minutes.

This will move the elements without having you rummaging around in folders outside VS and will also update your models and source control (assuming you've added your solution to source control) as you go.